# How to detect all http GET fails?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have a grid which fetches data via HTTP promises.  At the moment I can detect `errorCallback`s - as below:

```
myDataPromise.then(function () {
    //do stuff
}, function errorCallback(response) {
        if (response.statusText === "Not Found") {
            //do stuff
        }else if(response.statusText === "Internal Server Error"){
            //do stuff
        }
```

but say for an SSL error, where chrome fires back "ERR::CONNECTION REFUSED" I cannot pick up on this by reading the string as I can with 404's etc.  Really what I want is to display a simple image/text stating that there has been an error in retrieving one's data no matter what it is.  So if a http GET  fails *at all* - the user knows.  This seems to me like a fairly typical spec but I can't find much online regarding it.

Comment: u can check every http request using Interceptors :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

```
 // register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');


// alternatively, register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       // same as above
    },

    'response': function(response) {
       // same as above
    }
  };
});
```

The interceptor intercepts all the $http traffic. Even when you are loading templates.

Comment: How would this be called?  I'm having trouble seeing how this would fit in with my apply button function (which executes the "GET" function in a service, and returns a single or an array of promises).  If this makes sense?  Where would I invoke these functions?

Comment: You just add this interceptor to your application. Every $http request and response will go through this interceptor. If you get a response error, the interceptor executes the "responseError" function. You could handle this by emitting an event so you can handle it somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah got it working, wow that is an amazing bit of functionality!  Thanks for your help!